# SP2013 Change the look breakes on own template

Tags: error, theme, template

I took a standard Team Site and verified that the "Change the look" worked, I then saved the site as a template, and then created a new team site from that template and then the "Change the look" is broken, If I go the site settings / Composed looks, the list with all themes is there but empty.. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix?

We want to have blue border for open sites and red border for restricted sites..

regards
Martin

Comment: I also tried to just create a template using Powershell

$Web=Get-SPWeb http://Servername:port/yourSite
$Web.SaveAsTemplate(“Template Name”,”Template Title”,”Template Description”,1)

But still no luck..

Answer (score 1):

I regularly have the same issue.

There's a proposed solution by using SharePoint Designer to recreate the xslt of the Composed Looks list:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/16461c60-4831-44bd-af11-1f6d99e44ab6

But I may have an easier solution:
When you are saving the site template, just make sure that the "include contents" checkbox is checked.
Apparently, when you save the site with contents, it also saves the "Composed looks" list contents. You can then change the theme using "Change the look" option.